# checking latest version of a npm using http

Tags: npm

Is there a way to check the latest version of a package on npm using a http call? I wish to be able to do this programmatically in java and so do not wish to use `npm` directly.

Comment: You mean you what to get the lastes version of a NPM package usiong node js?

Comment: no.. checking an npm package - like `vega`

Comment: and what's up with the downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send a request to the public [npm registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry) endpoint;

```
https://registry.npmjs.org/<pkg_name>
```

Whereby the `<pkg_name>` part should be replaced with the actual name of the package.

For instance;

```
https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint
```

retrieves all JSON metadata for the [eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) package.

Then, as you can see [here](https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint), you'll need to parse the JSON response and obtain the actual latest version from:

```json
{
  "dist-tags": {
    "latest": "7.6.0",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get only the **latest version** of a package a [GET·/{package}/{version}](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REGISTRY-API.md#getpackageversion) endpoint could be used.

For example:

```bash
https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint/latest
```

then read `version` field from the json response:

```json
{
  "name": "eslint",
  "version": "8.37.0",
  ...
}
```